# Must provide query string error when getting data from graphql api react js next js

Tags: reactjs, django, graphql, next.js, graphene-django

when i use this code , it is saying please provide query string.. i am trying to get data from graphene api in django

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
const query_data = `query{
    forumPost(category:"web"){
      forumPostAuthor
      forumPostBody
      forumPostCode
      forumPostVote
      forumPostCategory
      forumPostLanguage1
      forumPostLanguage2
      forumPostLanguage3
      forumPostLanguage4
      forumPostLanguage5
      id
    }
  }`;

const request_parameters = {
    method: 'POST',
    header: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ query_data }),
};
const res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/', request_parameters);
const data = await res.json();

return {
    props: { data }
};
}
```

Comment: what? can you explain..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Graphene Django "Must provide query string"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44185188/graphene-django-must-provide-query-string) With a little hint: you're converting a string to JSON that is already a JSON string.